# How DBContext work with multiple User sessions in C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a MVC Web Application project plus a Class Library project. Now, I am trying to implement Entity Framework Transactions. So for that, I decided to go for Singleton pattern where I can make use of single DbContext object available throughout the Transaction. But later on, I found that Factory & UoW pattern is more suitable than Singleton. But, I have few questions and I did not find answers yet from online.

1. When we have single DbContext for the entire project using Factory & UoW pattern, What will happen if more than 1 user try to perform the same operation. Will they be working on the same DbContext or each user will be given unique DbContext to work within their Transaction??
2. If number of users work on the same DbContext in number of transactions, How to manage concurrency??

   It will be so much greatful if you can help me answer for my question.

Comment: You don't need explicit transactions, `SaveChanges` uses a transaction internally. You'd only need them if you followed the **bad** practice of trying to save each change to the database, the exact opposite of UoW. A DbContext is meant to be short-lived. Used that way it *is* a UoW container - all changes are kept in memory until you call `SaveChanges()` at the end of a request. No explicit transactions needed. A DbContext should **never** be used as a singleton in a web application

Comment: All ASP.NET MVC tutorials show a DbContext that's created and disposed in the controller action itself, or injected as a dependency to the constructor with a transient or scope lifetime. In both cases, the constructor lives only as long as the request, and so does the DbContext.

Comment: OK, Currently I have a `using` statement which initializes new DbContext in each methods which performs any CRUD operations. If I remove `using` statements and remove the `SaveChanges()` then methods which works based on the previous saved entries cannot be recognized until I perform final commit because the changes not saved into the db yet. How to make sure the NOT committed Changes are tracked inside a Transaction.

Comment: *Don't* remove `using`, *don't* remove `SaveChanges`. A DbContext is meant to work that way. When you use it that way there's no reason to use explicit transactions because `SaveChanges()` itself uses a transaction internally

Comment: But I need to wrap number of `SaveChanges()` into a single Transaction. How to achieve this??

Comment: There are no "not commited changes" either. Transactions are a *database* concept, not an EF concept. When you open a transaction, you open a connection to the database and execute `BEGIN TRAN`. The database transaction knows nothing about the changes tracked in the EF DbContext. The database transaction only learns about changes when a call to `SaveChanges` is made, which in turn executes SQL statements to insert/update/delete records in that transaction

Comment: Don't use multiple `SaveChanges`, that's the bug I mentioned in the first comment. If you only use a single `SaveChanges`, the context acts as a UoW. It's *meant* to work in this way - disconnected until it has to store changes to the database. You *don't* need to use `SaveChanges` multiple times either as the DbContext takes care of changed relations, new objects and their relations etc.

Comment: Is it correct that I can read the entries including the modified data within the Transaction before performing `SaveChanges` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You don't need single DbContext object, by design it should be instantiated with each request.
2. For disposing the object, choose using block or if you are using dependency injection it will be resolved by dependency injection / IoC containers.
3. About concurrency [Concurrency in Entity Framework](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework5/handle-concurrency-in-entity-framework.aspx):

> Entity Framework supports optimistic concurrency by default. EF saves an entity data to the database, assuming that the same data has not been changed since the entity was loaded. If it finds that the data has changed, then an exception is thrown and you must resolve the conflict before attempting to save it again.